# react-player lib. It is necessary to implement a smooth disappearance of the picture when you click on the play on light mode. For example delay 2 sec

Tags: reactjs, react-player

Perhaps there are other libraries that provide the necessary api.
My code looks like this

```
<ReactPlayer
            url={video?.videoUrl}
            playing={playVideo}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            muted={true}
            controls={true}
            loop={true}
            config={{
              playerVars: {
                showinfo: 0,
                rel: 0,
              },
            }}
            light={autoplay ? undefined : light}
            playIcon={
              autoplay ? (
                undefined
              ) : (
                <Button
                  form="circle"
                  size="3xxl"
                  iconRight={IconPlay}
                  onClick={handlePlay}
                />
              )
            }
          />
```

I would not like to resort to inserting a separate picture and setting a transition for it